# used <script src="sample.pdf"></script> in Html still the javascript code in pdf works

Tags: javascript, html

Recently in one of my code, in the script src, I used pdf file which had javascript code in it. Still, the javascript worked fine. Can I use any extension of the file in src which has Javascript, if so How does the browser detects the javascript code that is inside the pdf file.

Example of My usage

#### index.html

```
<html>
 <title> Sample </title>
 <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

 <script src="js/sample.pdf"></script>
 <body>
  <h1>Sample page to test the script tag</h1>
 </body>
</html>
```

#### js/sample.pdf

```
$(document).ready(function(){
consloe.log('it works');
});
```

Comment: Why do you want place a `PDF` file inside a script tag to start with?

Comment: `js/sample.pdf` - that isn't a PDF file, that is a javascript file with the extension `.pdf`

Comment: In HTML5, the default value for the `script[type]` attribute is the one of javascript application. It may do some lazy MIME type checking, but since javascript MIMEs are various,  all `application/...` and `text/...` might be seen as valid.

Comment: @DarkBee I was experimenting the usage and the wanted to if it works or not.  So had placed pdf file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HTML5, the default value for the [`script[type]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-type) attribute is the one of [javascript application](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#javascript-mime-type).

Browsers will do some MIME type checks in order to allow only executable MIMEs which means that all `application/...` might be seen as valid, and only some `text/...` will be too.

---

**[edit]** According to [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement),

> The script should be served with the `text/javascript` MIME type, but browsers are lenient and only block them if the script is served with an image type (`image/*`), a video type (`video/*`), an audio (`audio/*`) type, or `text/csv`.

---

Here is a snippet **which only works in chrome*** showing a few examples of weirdly accepted and refused MIME types :

```js
function loadScript(type, magics){
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  const magic_array = new Uint8Array(magics.split(' ').map(n=>parseInt(n, 16)));
  script.src = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(magic_array, {type: type}));
  script.dataset.id = type;
  script.onerror = e => console.log(type, 'failed');
  script.onload = e => console.log(type, 'success');
  document.head.appendChild(script);
  }
loadScript('image/png', '89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a'); // fails
loadScript('application/zip', '50 4B 03 04'); // works
loadScript('text/css', ''); // works
loadScript('text/csv', ''); // fails
loadScript('text/plain', ''); // works
loadScript('application/octet-stream', '4D 5A'); // works
loadScript('application/exe', '4D 5A'); // works
```

*****FF doesn't respect the MIME type and doesn't triggers its magic number's checking on blobURIs... But I did test on my local server and when it sends these MIMEs, the results are the same.